# Ghostscript command line parameters to convert EPS to PDF

Tags: windows, command-line, parameters, ghostscript

Just installed Ghostscript 8.54 for Windows.

Does anyone know of the minimum parameters to pass to `gswin32c.exe` to make it convert, say, *someFile.eps* to *someFile.eps.pdf*?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since the question was about the *"minimum parameters to pass to gswin32c.exe to make it convert, say, someFile.eps to someFile.eps.pdf"*, let me give an answer:

```
  c:/path/to/gswin32c.exe ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -o c:/path/to/output.pdf ^
    c:/path/to/input.eps
```

or even shorter:

```
  gswin32c ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -o output.pdf ^
    input.eps
```

This will use the builtin, default parameters for Ghostscript. The most important of which, from the top of my head, for the most recent version of Ghostscript are:

- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default` ........ roughly the same settings as Adobe Distiller uses for "screen" with the following differences:
- `-r720x720` .................................. resolution: 720 dpi (bitmaps/fonts requiring conversion to bitmap)
- `-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged` ... (Distiller's "screen" uses `=/sRGB`)
- `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4` .... (Distiller's "screen" uses `=1.3`)
- `-dEmbedAllFonts=true` [*]......... (Distiller's "screen" uses `=false`)
- `-dOptimize=false` [**] ............... (Distiller's "screen" uses `=true`)
- `-dDownsample{Color,Gray,Mono}Images=false` ... (Distiller's "screen" uses `=true`)

<sub>[*] By default, Ghostscript does not embed the classical *"Base 14"*-PostScript fonts. To enforce that, use an extra parameter (at the end of the command line!) like `-c "<</NeverEmbed [ ]>>setdistillerparams" -f c:/path/to/input.pdf`.</sub>
<sub>[**] Ghostscript's *pdfwrite* device cannot "optimize" a PDF when it is writing it the first time. To optimize, you have to call Ghostscript again for a second pass, using special parameters (you may also try `-dOptimize=true`).</sub>

BTW, Ghostscript's most recent version is 8.71, available here: [ghostscript.com/relases](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/).

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a decent bit of time.  It's unfortunate that yours is not the selected answer.

Comment: Indeed, I wish this was the selected answer too. Btw "_-r720x720 . resolution: 720 dpi_" - 720? Ain't that a bit too much? Should it maybe be 72 instead? Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: The default resolution of Ghostscript's `pdfwrite` device *indeed* is 720 dpi. The default resolution of the image output devices (such as `tiffg4`, `jpeg`, `png`, `ppm`, `pbm`...) is 72 dpi.

Comment: Hah, I would have never guessed that - thanks for the clarification, @pipitas ; cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: You could ask a new SO question about how to find out *all* the default settings for any Ghostscript output device... and I'd answer that. Heh  :-)

Comment: Many thanks, @pipitas - I'd actually love to know that; question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001107) `:)` - cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, although depending on version of Ghostscript, `-o output.pdf` might not work - I had to use `-sOutputFile=output.pdf`

Answer (score 5):

Under Windows, ps2pdf and other utilities are located in `C:\Program Files\gs\gs#.##\lib` as .bat and .cmd files. This isn't exactly obvious, especially if you're looking for .exe files.

Comment: what you say, is not necessarily true (but still helpful for some people). It all depends on what you chose when installing. A user (or his administrator) may have chosen a non-default path, or drive d:, when installing Ghostscript. and `c:\program files` is `c:\programme` on German installations. But you can overcome this by saying: *Usually, Ghostscript versions install into `%programfiles%\gs\gs#.##\*`*. Because %programfiles% is an environment variable that points to the default insta path on all locales, be it `c:\program files` or `d:\programme`...